# Elements form array.map don't render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to render elements from my state (array) but they don't want render on the screen. If I perform `console.log(b.name)` it logs my names in console.

```
renderAllElements() {
    this.state.myData.map(b => {
        return(
            <div>
                <h4>{b.name}</h4>
            </div>
        )
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.renderAllElements()}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: What is in `this.state.myData`?

Comment: return the map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return back your map :

```
renderAllElements() {
  return this.state.myData.map(b => {
      return(
        <div>
            <h4>{b.name}</h4>
        </div>
     )
  })
}
```

Comment: Oh yes! I'm so distracted :D

Comment: @Mac Guess these mistakes are common with all devs :D

Answer (score 2):

You are correctly invoking your `renderAllElements()` function in your render method. You also seem to correctly map through your array variable, but the function doesn't return anything back to render once finished mapping.

Simply add a return for your map function and it should work:

```
renderAllElements() {
  return this.state.myData.map(b => {
      return(
        <div>
            <h4>{b.name}</h4>
        </div>
     )
  })
}
```

One-liner alternative:

```
renderAllElements() {
  return this.state.myData.map(b => <div><h4>{b.name}</h4></div>);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already use array functions you can alternatively rewrite it without curly braces:

```
renderAllElements = () => (
    this.state.myData.map(b => (
        <div>
            <h4>{b.name}</h4>
        </div>
    ));
)
```

So you don't need to remember about return statement :)